# Does $SW_X\not\neq 0 \implies \hat{A}(X)\neq 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $X^4$ be a closed spin 4-manifold with $b_2^+\geq 2$ and let
$$
SW_X:\mathrm{Spin}^c(X)\to \mathbb{Z}
$$
be the Seiberg-Witten map. If either $\hat{A}(X)\neq 0$ or $SW_X\not \equiv 0$, then $X$ admits no metric of positive scalar curvature. (See any reference on SW equations, e.g. Morgan or Moore.)

My question is whether in dimension 4, the Seiberg-Witten invariants provide a "stronger" obstruction to positive scalar curvature. More precisely,

**Question:** Let $X^4$ be a closed spin 4-manifold with $b_2^+\geq 2$ and at least one SW basic class, i.e. $SW_X\not\equiv 0$. Then must we have $\hat{A}(X)\neq 0$?

**My idea:** For spin 4-manifolds, $\hat{A}(X)$ is related to the signature:
$$
\hat{A}(X)=-\frac{1}{8}\sigma(X).
$$
So the answer to the question is negative if and only if there exists a closed *spin* 4-manifold satisfying

1. $b_2^+\geq 2$,
2. $\sigma(X)=0$, and
3. $SW_X\not \equiv 0$.

[Akhmedov and Park](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3346.pdf) have constructed exotic copies of $S^2\times S^2$ with nontrivial SW invariants, but $b_2^+(S^2\times S^2)=1$, so this doesn't give a counterexample.

Maybe combining the formula for the dimension of the SW moduli space with the index formula of the Dirac operator $D^+_A$ would imply that $\sigma(X)$ cannot vanish if $SW_X\neq 0$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My understanding is that the Ahkmedov and Park paper has a few potential issues, so is not yet accepted by the mathematical community at large.  I am not a 4 manifold topologist, though, so I could be very wrong.